# Converting fixed length columns in bash

Tags: bash, dataframe, command-line, html-table, data-wrangling

I have a text file generated using `curl -s <URL> | lynx -stdin -dump -nomargins -width=9999`

It looks something like this:

```
name1  yes  yes           no   no 
name2  yes  yes  10   12  no   yes
name3  no   no   139  11  yes  no
```

So if I understand my file correctly each line has the same width in characters, but where there is missing data there is just spaces instead of NA or something usable.

I want to convert this into a tab separated file with NA or nothing where the data for the column is missing.

I know there is a way to do this in Excel using data import with fixed colujmn width, and R solution with `read.fwf()`, but I would like to find a bash solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `${line:start:length}` substring operator to extract fixed-column substrings of the line.

Comment: How will you determine the length of each column? I think `lynx` will change them based on the maximum length of values in each column.

Comment: please update the question with the expected output

Comment: @JNevill That won't work because some of the fields are empty. Look at the first line.

Comment: @Barmar Oof. Yeah. That's not good. And to your point, since the length of each column is unknown until the output is produced, it's not safe to specify `FIELDWIDTHS` :/ I will delete my comment.

Comment: Parsing the input HTML is probably a more robust approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- a `GNU awk` solution is acceptable
- data in all columns is left-justified
- column data does not contain embedded spaces

To simulate the `lynx` output:

```
$ cat lynx.out
name1  yes  yes           no   no
name2  yes  yes  10   12  no   yes
name3  no   no   139  11  yes  no
name4       yes       3   no
```

**NOTE:** Following answers require `GNU awk 4.0+` for

- 3rd argument to `asorti()`
- 4th argument to `split()`

Assuming `lynx` output can be captured to an output file (`lynx.out`), one `GNU awk` idea requiring 2 passes of the input file:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { OFS="\t" }
FNR==NR { gsub(/ *$/,"")                                     # strip trailing spaces from line
          n=split($0,a," {1,}",seps)                         # split line on 1+ spaces, storing fields in a[] array and groups of spaces in seps[] array; note: a[1] == $1, a[2] == $2; key objective is to capture length of each group of spaces
          sum=0
          for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {                             # loop through our fields and associated seps[] array entries
              colpos[sum+1]                                  # keep track of all column positions as indexes of the colpos[] array
              sum= sum + length($i seps[i])
          }
          next
        }
FNR==1  { n=asorti(colpos,start,"@ind_num_asc") }            # sort column positions in numerical order; start[] array contents will contain the positions sorted in nuemrical order
        { sep=""
          for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {                               # loop through list of positions extracing data via substr() calls
              val=substr($0,start[i], start[i+1]==0 ? length($0) : start[i+1]-start[i])
              gsub(/ *$/,"",val)                             # strip trailing spaces from valu
              if (! val) val="NA"
              printf "%s%s",sep,val
              sep=OFS
          }
          print ""
        }
' lynx.out lynx.out
```

Same concept but using a single pass through the data (input from a file or stdin) and assuming the entire `lynx` output can be saved in memory (via the `lines[]` array):

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { sub(/ *$/,"")
        lines[++c]=$0                                       # save current line in memory
        n=split($0,a," {1,}",seps)
        sum=0
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            colpos[sum+1]
            sum= sum + length($i seps[i])
        }
      }

END   { n=asorti(colpos,start,"@ind_num_asc")
        for (lineno=1;lineno<=c;lineno++) {                 # loop through array of input lines
            sep=""
            for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
                val=substr(lines[lineno],start[i], start[i+1]==0 ? length(lines[lineno]) : start[i+1]-start[i])
                gsub(/ *$/,"",val)
                if (! val) val="NA"
                printf "%s%s",sep,val
                sep=OFS
            }
            print ""
        }
      }
'
```

**NOTES:**

- invoke one of 2 ways:
- `cat lynx.out | awk '....'`
- `awk '.....' lynx.out`

Both of these generate:

```
name1   yes     yes     NA      NA      no      no
name2   yes     yes     10      12      no      yes
name3   no      no      139     11      yes     no
name4   NA      yes     NA      3       no      NA
```

Modifying the code to replace `"NA"` with `""` generates:

```
name1   yes     yes                     no      no
name2   yes     yes     10      12      no      yes
name3   no      no      139     11      yes     no
name4           yes             3       no
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a multi-pass Perl option. Optimisation is surely possible.

The basic idea is to find the offsets where we never have field data and put tabs there.

Sample input to lynx:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>name1</td><td>yes</td><td>maybe</td><td></td><td></td><td>no</td><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>name2</td><td>yes</td><td>yes</td><td>10</td><td>12</td><td>no</td><td>yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>name4</td><td></td><td>maybe not</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>name3</td><td>no</td><td>no</td><td>139</td><td>11</td><td>yes</td><td>no</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

Sample output from `lynx -stdin -dump -nomargins -width=9999`:

```
name1 yes maybe            no  no
name2 yes yes       10  12 no  yes
name4     maybe not
name3 no  no        139 11 yes no
```

Process with Perl. Offsets with zero count can become tabs.

```
$ <lynx.out perl -nle '
    $cols[ $-[0] ]++ while /[^ ]/g;
    print $_, "\n", map {$_||"-"} @cols;

    END {
        @offsets = grep { !$cols[$_] } 0..$#cols;
        print "\n", "@offsets";
    }
'
name1 yes maybe            no  no
11111-111-11111------------11--11
name2 yes yes       10  12 no  yes
22222-222-22211-----11--11-22--221
name4     maybe not
33333-222-33322-111-11--11-22--221
name3 no  no        139 11 yes no
44444-332-44322-111-221-22-331-331

5 9 15 19 23 26 30
```

We can perform tab substitution with a little adjustment to the code
(using `|` here instead of actual tabs for clarity):

```
$ <lynx.out perl -nle '
    push @lines, $_;
    $cols[ $-[0] ]++ while /[^ ]/g;

    END {
        @offsets = grep { !$cols[$_] } 0..$#cols;

        for (@lines) {
                         # pad short lines
            $line = $_ . " " x (@cols-length);

            substr($line,$_,1) = "|" for @offsets;
            print $line;
        }
    }
'
name1|yes|maybe|   |   |  |no |no 
name2|yes|yes  |   |10 |12|no |yes
name4|   |maybe|not|   |  |   |   
name3|no |no   |   |139|11|yes|no
```

An extra column has appeared. This is unavoidable when the input is ambiguous (as in this example). If cells cannot contains space, this will not be an issue.

Finally, strip leading and trailing space between "tabs". For example, by adding before the final print:

```
        $line =~ s/ *\| */|/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

if u just want them aligned well, different column widths, but allowing for spaces within columns :

**INPUT :**

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>name1</td><td>yes</td><td>maybe</td><td></td><td></td><td>no</td><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>name2</td><td>yes</td><td>yes</td><td>10</td><td>12</td><td>no</td><td>yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>name4</td><td></td><td>maybe not</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>name3</td><td>no</td><td>no</td><td>139</td><td>11</td><td>yes</td><td>no</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

**CODE/OUTPUT:**

```
{m,g}awk'
BEGIN {
     RS = "(^.+[<]table[>]\n|[<][/]td[>][<][/]tr[>]\n)"\
              "[<]tr[>][<]td[>]|[<][/]td[>][<][/]tr[>]\n"\
              "[<][/]table[>].+$"
     FS = "[<][/]td[>][<]td[>]"
    OFS = "\t"
 } 
 gsub("\t\t","\tNA\t",$!(NF=NF)) + gsub("\t\t","\tNA\t")+\
  sub("^\t", "NA&")              +  sub( "\t$", "&NA" )^_' 


name1   yes maybe   NA  NA  no  no
name2   yes yes 10  12  no  yes
name4   NA  maybe not   NA  NA  NA  NA
name3   no  no  139 11  yes no
```

but since tabs are inherently not well-aligned without some formatting help, tag on

> ```
> ……… | column -s$'\411' -t
> ```

at tail end of pipe chain to make (the `\411` bit is essential to prevent spaces being ruined)

```
name1  yes  maybe      NA   NA  no   no
name2  yes  yes        10   12  no   yes
name4  NA   maybe not  NA   NA  NA   NA
name3  no   no         139  11  yes  no
```